# Nested List Question

Tags: c#, list, nested

I have a question about Nested Lists.

I have a class similar to the following...

```
public class Order
{
    private Guid id;
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ID { get { return id; } set { id = value; }}

    private List<Items> orderItems;
    [DataMember]
    public List<Items> OrderItems { get { return orderItems; } set {   orderItems= value; } }

}

public class Items
{
    private string itemName;
    [DataMember]
    public string ItemName { get { return itemName; } set { itemName = value; }}

 }
```

This seems to be ok until i reference the list within in my code saying something similar to

```
if myItemName = this.order.orderItems[0].itemName
```

The problem comes when I add the "[0].itemName".  Can anyone help me with what I am missing?

Comment: add the "[0].itemName"? Do you mean assigning a value or adding?

Comment: What is actually happening?  A compile error?  Run-time error?  Are you ever assigning orderItems or is it left as null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be trying to access the private field rather than the public property.  Try: (note the case change)

```
myItemName = this.order.OrderItems[0].ItemName
```

Also, the syntax looks weird, what language are you using? Did you mean:

```
if ( this.order.OrderItems.Count > 0 && myItemName == this.order.OrderItems[0].ItemName ) ...
```

Comment: that was my first reaction, he accesses the private field of the item class.

Comment: yes that was it.  sorry late night, not sure how the private item was even showing up in InteliSense.

Thanks.